# isSubstring method in ML

Tags: sml, ml

```
fun appear(x:string,y:string)=
if String.isSubstring x y then print("APPEAR ") else  print("NOT APPEAR ");
appear("abc","asabcbc");
```

I wrote this function and compiled in Moskow ML.But there is an error like this:

```
! Unbound value component: String.isSubstring
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using an outdated version of Moscow ML. Try [version 2.10](http://mosml.org) or later, which has `String.isSubstring`.